# Use HtmlHelper class in Javascript or jquery Template

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, jquery-templates

I want to use Html Helper in javaScript like

```
starting += '</div>';
starting += '<div class="widget-body">';
starting += '<div class="widget-main">';
starting += '&nbsp;' + result.employeeTimelineList[i].Details + '';
starting += '<span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp; ' + @Html.DisplayLocalTime(result.employeeTimelineList[i].CreatedOnUtc, (Company)Session[Constants.Session.COMPANY]) +'</span>';
starting += '<div class="space-6">';
starting += '</div>';
```

where @Html.DisplayLocalTime is my html helper class which  i want to use here. But i am getting error in line

```
result.employeeTimelineList[i].CreatedOnUtc
```

`result` is not define in current context and also getting error on `i`is not define in current context.

i tried use jquery template for this but there also i am not able to use the htmlHelper class, Please tell me the any solution.

Comment: Yes because you are trying to use javascript variable in .net i'm talking about i.

Comment: You need to quote the html helper `... + '@Html.DisplayLocalTime(....)' + '</span>';`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define it in a single codes

like below:

```
'@result.employeeTimelineList[i].CreatedOnUtc'
```

Please use like:

```
starting += "&nbsp;" + '@result.employeeTimelineList[i].Details' +"";
```

Comment: i tried this  '@result.employeeTimelineList[i].CreatedOnUtc' in Html Helper but the Helper takes two arguments first is Datetime and by putting this inside   ' ' treated as string.